# Pin IDF xtensa gcc toolchain to specific version

Tags: c++, gcc, esp32

I'm trying to get OpenCV to build from [this repo](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv) but also include the `objdetect` module. Problem is installing IDF always downloads the latest toolchain, which has a GCC upgrade and breaks parts of OpenCV. Newer GCC is probably better, but I assume it'll take longer to fix the OpenCV issues than use an older revision of the toolchain. How to I pin IDF to use a specific xtensa compiler?

Comment: If you want to use an older version of GCC you can install an older esp-idf version. If you cloned the esp-idf git repository you can simply checkout an older version: `git checkout v4.4.1`, then run the install script to download the required tools.

Comment: This answers the question for me, so I'm happy to mark it as such if you post this as an answer! One other detail I found is that in the `tools.json` file in the esp-idf repo you can see what version of the toolchain would be used. Not sure if there is another easier way without checking each version of esp-idf

Comment: Or just upvote the comment to indicate that it was useful.  I'm not worried about scoring virtual points.

Comment: Sure, but it also helps the UI and anyone in the future looking for a solved question :)

Comment: OK, since you insisted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an older version of GCC you can install an older esp-idf version. If you cloned the esp-idf git repository you can simply checkout an older version: `git checkout v4.4.1`, then run the install script to download the required tools.

Note (by [@GKruger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194320/gkruger)): One can also inspect the `tools/tools.json` file in the git repository for toolchain version numbers and download paths to the required tools.